# Search Result Template not sticking

Tags: display-template

I'm having a weird problem and I hope someone can help.

I created a custom search result template, I added a search result web part, then selected it from the "Item Display Template" dropdown and applied it. The search results show properly up to this point, but when I stop editing the page the template reverts to the previous one. Any ideas why this is happening? I first tested it on O365 SharePoint and is working and staying but when I try it on our client server (on premises sharepoint 2013) it does what I mentioned before, it just goes away. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the files are published and approved.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amal Hashhim noted check your file and be sure they are published along with any ancillary files you may be using (CSS, JavaScript).

Also be sure that you are clicking OK or Apply when you update the webpart properties.  If you don't do that and you navigate away or refresh the page your changes for the webpart will not be saved.